# Can stripped hole in a motherboard be repaired?

Tags: repair, fan, motherboard

I was doing an SSD upgrade and the fan is held to the motherboard by screws. When I went to re-install the fan, the hole/nut in the motherboard seems to be stripped. Can this be repaired? What do hardware techs do when they are faced with this? My concern is to secure the fan back the way it was.

At time index 1:59 this video shows the same spot I'm referring to where I had the problem:
https://youtu.be/w4nLqjL5V2s?t=119

[image]
[image]

Comment: A photo showing the kind of hardware used to mount the screws would help.

Comment: You talking about the CPU cooling fan?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, the CPU cooling fan. This is in a Mac Mini.

Comment: @ThePhoton This video is the same model I was working on. At the time index of 1:59, you can see the same spot I was having the problem. When he removes the fan, you can see what the screw went into on the motherboard:
https://youtu.be/w4nLqjL5V2s?t=119

Comment: Aren't they just screwed into plastic bosses that protrude through the mombo?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I believe you are right. For some reason, I wasn't able to screw this back in. I kept turning the tool and it wouldn't go back in. It felt like it must be stripped.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks, in the circled photo, the problem area is the upper right.